# Can I use Azure offline sync API with Azure Storage Emulator?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-emulator

I am trying to get [Azure offline sync](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync/) for mobile apps working. I'd like to use that API with the "[Azure Storage Emulator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/)".

Do these two things work together? There is no mention of whether this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offline data sync cannot use the storage emulator - you need to think of the storage emulator simply as a test endpoint for Azure Storage. Offline sync works with SQLite and Core Data.

Also remember that the Azure storage emulator runs specifically on a Windows development machine; you cannot install it on an Android / iOS / Windows Phone device.

Comment: I wouldn't try install it on those OSs, just wanted something local and fast for testing offline sync. Hopefully in a future version!

Comment: You can run a local server with SQLite3 (node) or SQL Server (ASP.NET) for testing purposes.  However, you won't easily be able to use authentication or push notifications as those functions require Azure.  If you really wanted to test locally, you could set up a /.auth/login/local endpoint in your code that can be used to return a test JWT.  All of this is documented in the HOWTO docs on the azure.com website.

Comment: @AdrianHall Thanks Adrian. Though it seems way too complicated for something that I hoped would minimise complexity... So I'll do the obvious thing and just use Azure as intended! :-)